# To create WCF service Setup to install in IIS Server

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

How to create WCF service's Package and Deployment Setup using VS 2008 to install in IIS Server? Shall we call this service from our Windows application ?

EDIT:

I have got an answer below. Also, it worked fine for me when I have hosted it like a web application in the IIS Web Server.

Comment: I'm a newbie in WCF. Please provide me the steps to create a setup.

Comment: It can be created via a Web Setup or can host like a web application in the web server. (WCF requisites should be installed in the server.)

Answer (score 1):

Use Web setup:

[image]

Additionally look at the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/04/28/Configuring-WCF-and-IIS-7-With-HTTP-Bindings-and-Multiple.aspx

http://archdipesh.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-do-i-deployhost-wcf-service-on.html